# nan value in an array without this value?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to find the min and max value of an array in python. my array is `float64 (1932,1932)`. when I used `np.min(array)` or `np.max(array)` it returns nan. but I do not have nan value in the array. do you know what is the problem? and how can I solve it?
Thanks

```
BD_D_Q=np.zeros((m,m))
BD_D_R=np.zeros((m,m))
BD_D_Q,BD_D_R=BD_distance(psnr_bitrate)
min_BDQ=np.min(BD_D_Q)
max_BDQ=np.max(BD_D_Q)
min_BDR=np.min(BD_D_R)
tmp=BD_D_R
tmp[tmp==np.inf]=0
max_BDR=np.max(tmp)
```

Comment: Please show is the exact code.  Saying `float64 (1932,1932)` could mean many things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.min(array[~np.isnan(array)]) #means the min of the non NaN values

print(array[np.isnan(array)]) #will print any NaN value
```

Comment: is it possible to have the index of nan value?

Comment: `np.argwhere(np.isnan(array))`

Comment: Do you remember that the indexes are 0 based? We cannot do anything without access to your data.

Comment: how do I remove rows that have nan value?

Comment: `array=array[~np.isnan(array)]) `